# Does it make sense to suggest a "*BSD" Q&A site on Area 51?

Tags: discussion

"Unix and Linux" covers UNIXoidal systems as well (or so I assume).

But since there are sites like askubuntu.com, does it make sense to open up a page for *BSD and its derivates, or should those users stick to unix.SE?

Comment: Hmm, In the last years, I've asked a couple of *BSD related questions. Not only most of them are never answered, but they never even get a lot of views. Maybe it does make sense making a board dedicated to *BSD...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ask Ubuntu is a [special case](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/ubuntu-stack-exchange-is-askubuntu-com/) for the Stack Exchange network. An Area 51 proposal specifically for BSD related questions would [likely not be supported](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/merging-season/) by Stack Overflow Internet Services.

In any case, as far as I know, questions about BSD and BSD derivatives are on topic here:

- [bsd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bsd)
- [freebsd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/freebsd)
- [openbsd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openbsd)
- [netbsd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/netbsd)

Also, the [site FAQ](https://unix.stackexchange.com/faq) specifically mentions FreeBSD.

Comment: If you can also point to the [FAQ](http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq)...